# Automation tool of ADF web-based application with integration in JIRA

Tags: automation, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I'm looking for a non-regression test automation tool :

- For web applications using **ADF technology.**
- It also needs to be integrated with **JIRA.**

These are my two imperatives.

Of course, I found Selenium which is the unavoidable tool.

However, my manager would like me to submit several tools that I would have audited. Do you have some tracks or experiences that I could use in order to submit several tools to him?

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For unit/non regression testing you can use :

- JUnit as it is integrated with Jdevelloper 
  (see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/part5-083468.html)
- JUnit is integrated with Jira (see https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/writing-and-running-plugin-tests/create-and-run-unit-tests)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Oracle Developer Cloud Service as a platform that combines issue tracking and DevOps+test automation with specific support for ADF built-in:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/agile_development_with_oracle_developer
Selenium - there is an ADF extension to it:
https://github.com/adfemg/adf-selenium

Comment: One more testing tool - Oracle Application Testing Suite - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/index.html , http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/ds-ats-adf-testing-accelerator-200156.pdf